# Is sets intersections distributive?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W_1$, $W_2$, $W_3$ be three sets or vector spaces,
Is it always right to say if $W_1\cap W_2=W_1\cap W_3=W_2\cap W_3=\{0\}$
Then also $W_3\cap(W_1+W_2)=\{0\}$?
What is a counter example?

My counter example is $w_1=\operatorname{span}((1,0))$, $w_2=\operatorname{span}((0,1))$, $w_3=\operatorname{span}((1,1))$

Comment: Please use TeX markup for your formulae. Without it it often becomes unclear what you're meaning since you may have to resort to use ASCII characters to not mean what the normally mean. It's really unclear what your question is, you seem to ask if something is true, but include a counterexample for it, implying that what you ask the truth of is indeed false.

Comment: Just instead of the sign '@' use the intersection sign between sets.

Comment: @obareey Do you really think it's that clear that he by W1+W2 meant the union? And that he by {0} meant the empty set? According to the commentaries it looks like he by W1+W2 actually meant addition and by {0} meant the null space (ie a set containing 0). The example he's referring to is three vector spaces.

Comment: It's still quite unclear what you're asking for. You've provided a counter example of your statement, yet you seem to ask if the statement is true!? If you have a counter example to a statement the statement should be false.

Comment: @skyking I'm sorry, I didn't read it through. I will be more careful.

Comment: Its written in notebook as addition and not union, I myself dont know which one they mean, 0 here is the set that includes only 0

Comment: One does not say that an operation is (by itself) distributive.  Distributivity is a relationship between two operations (as when ordinary multiplication distributes over ordinary addition).  You seem to be considering whether set intersection distributes over summation of vector subspaces, but again, this is not an intrinsic property of set intersection (truth or falsity depends on what second operation is involved).

Comment: Hey thank you very much for your answer, in this case according to my example its false to say so right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, think of intersection as "and" and union as "or". First statement is $x$ is not in $W_{i}$ and $W_{j}$ for any $i,j$. Hence $x$ is not in $W_{i}$ and ($W_{j}$ or $W_{k}$)

Try to draw a Venn diagram aswell.

Comment: But take for example: W1=1,0 w2=0,1 w3=1,1 all three intersections is zero but w3@(w1+w2)=1,1

Comment: what are those? point in $R^{2}$ or just one point subsets or $N$ ?

Comment: Vector spaces, w1 x axis w2 y axis w3 sum of them

Comment: Added a comment

Comment: Hey I cant read your comment its full of signs and strange letters!

Comment: If they are points in R2 then they are all "disjoint" and distinct. you might be thinking of thier projection on the axes which is something diffrent